# Transpose of a Matrix. Hackerrank Test Case Fail

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

I am struggling with a fairly simple question in hackerrank. The question  asks to input a square matrix and print it's transpose. The question can be found here after registering for the contest. The name of the question is Transpose Matrix:
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/csdp-contest/challenges/

My solution to this question in Java code is below:

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line1[] = br.readLine().split(" ");//Read the first line to find the size of the array
            int n = line1.length;
            int ar[][] = new int[n][n];//initialize an integer array with size n
            int rowNumber = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
                ar[rowNumber][i] = Integer.parseInt(line1[i]);//Store the first line in the array
            rowNumber = 1;
            //Store the next input lines in the array if any
            for (int j=0;j<n-1;j++){
                String line[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
                for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){
                    ar[rowNumber][i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
                }
                rowNumber++;
            }
            //Print the transpose of the matrix by printing ar[j][i] instead of [i][j]
            for(int i=0;i<rowNumber;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<rowNumber;j++){
                    System.out.print(ar[j][i]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code passes the test case given along with the question, but it fails one of the test cases when I submit. I can't understand if I am missing any edge cases or is there a bug in the code. Can you please help me figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this quiz, but typically the number type is a frequent gotcha (like overflows in int arithmetic etc).

Here you seem not to have any arithmetic problem, but it's always worth it to re-read the question and check the assumptions (input format maybe?)

Comment: Oh God! after you said re-read the question, I did that and it was not mentioned clearly about the type of data the array can hold. I assumed that the array contains only integer element. Changed the array to type "String" and it worked. Thanks a lot!. But I feel the question description is also to be blamed a bit.